# how to convert audio (.3gpp) file to video file?

Tags: conversion, multimedia

I've a pure audio file having extension of .3gpp. How to convert it into a video file? As it doesn't contain any video, so a blank screen would suffice. I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04. Also I'm converting the audio to video so as to upload in facebook which doesn't accept audio file directly. (I know there are other methods to upload an audio indirectly on facebook like `soundcloud` and then the link to `soundcloud` will be there in facebook. But this I don't want now. I want to upload directly audio like a video on facebook)

Googling, I found `FF Multi Converter`. But it couldn't be installed properly and also I don't know whether it would solve my purpose.

Also I installed `VLC media player` in my system Ubuntu 16.04. There I converted the .3gpp audio file into mp4. Please look at the format of video selected below:

[image: format of converted video selected]

The converted file (174.8) is larger than the original one (131.5 MB).
The converted file is running on Ubuntu's defaut video player (Totem) but unable to play properly in VLC media player. So, I'm in a doubt if I upload this video file in facebook, whether it will work properly. Also can you suggest whether VLC media player can convert audio to video as I did and mentioned above?

Please suggest me any easy way to get the audio converted to video.

Also, googling I found any picture can be added to make the audio a video file but what tool in ubuntu Will convert it into video file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Slideshow](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow) you can make a video from a jpeg with `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img.jpg -c:v libx264 -t 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4`, and you can copy the audio at the same time with

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img.jpg -i audio.m4a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest out.mp4
```

to make the output file stop when the audio runs out. There are other examples as well in the `ffmpeg` wiki.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at ffmpeg? It's a tool that can convert a huge number of multimedia codecs into other codecs.

Comment: ffmpeg may be the answer, but it would help both the original poster and people who find this question later to provide more details. This `answer` would have been better posted as a comment.

Comment: No, ffmpeg didn't work. I used ffmpeg to convert the audio into .mp4. It converted but while uploading on Facebook, it messaged that the file doesn't appear to be a valid video file & the upload failed. Googling I found any picture can be used to make it video but what tool in ubuntu Will convert it into video file?

Comment: @icarus I edited & added last paragraph in my Q.

Comment: According to http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow you can make a video from a jpeg with `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img.jpg -c:v libx264 -t 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4`, and you can handle the audio side with `ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img.jpg -i audio.m4a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest out.mp4` to make the output file stop when the audio runs out. There are other examples as well.

Comment: @icarus yes it is in process. Just, in the mean time, till it is converting can you please tell me to reduce the output file size, what more I can do? The video it is making should consume the lowest size as it is of no use. May you please suggest how to reduce the final size? Also please address my name in your comment so that I'm notified.

Comment: @icarus your method has worked fine. If you post it as answer I can accept so that other viewers can benefit. Thanks